# ipycanvas can not show image with javascript error

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets, ipycanvas

I am running the basic ipycanvas sample code

```
from ipywidgets import Image

sprite1 = Image.from_file("lena.jpeg")

canvas = Canvas(width=300, height=300)

canvas.fill_style = "#a9cafc"
canvas.fill_rect(0, 0, 300, 300)

canvas.draw_image(sprite1, 50, 50)

canvas
```

I get a javacript error
in the chrome developer tool, I see the error
Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:8888/static/ipycanvas.js?v=20230418165310' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

What could be wrong. I have been playing with ipycanvas and ipywidgets versions all day.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably using Jupyter Lab, try Jupyter Notebook instead

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).